# Is it safe to combine RIO fields and properties?

Tags: mvvmcross

I've been looking at [the N=36 tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-5XQlcVj2Y) which introduces new RIO support in MvvmCross 3.09.  Is it safe to combine `INC` fields and old school properties in the same class?  I ask because some of my property setters and getters are complex so it maybe be easier to leave them as-is.  However the vast majority of my existing properties are simple and as such seem excellent candidates for fields.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'safe' is an *interesting* word to use here - I'm not entirely sure what it means in this context.

I personally believe it is *safe* to mix and match `INotifyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the same project and in the same view model - there's nothing that should go **bang** as a result and the memory and processing speed performance of `INotifyChanged` should be as good as or better than the performance of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The only potential areas of *unsafe* risk I can think of are:

- team development and later code maintenance - using the two different approaches together might confuse yourself or other coders either now or later in maintenance - it would be fair for them to ask "where do I use one approach or the other?" and "why?"
- lack of 'change all' support - `INotifyPropertyChanged` allows ViewModels to send a *everything has changed* notification - they can do this using a `null` or empty property name. `INotifyChanged` does not currently join in with this notification. In my experience, this 'change all' mechanism is used very infrequently and is not well known by Mvvm developers - so the risk here is small. However, if anyone did try to use it, then they might be surprised that the `INotifyChanged` bound-fields didn't update.
- portability to other Mvvm libraries - Rio is a binding mechanism MvvmCross has introduced - so it isn't yet available in other Mvvm platforms. If you were ever to port back to something like Prism then this might be a risk for you (you might have to rewrite those fields as properties)
- confusing to Windows developers - experienced Xaml developers have been used to using `INotifyPropertyChanged` all the way back to 2005 - so it might confuse them to have to use the [MvvmCross Xaml Binding Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.BindingEx/) in order to get the fields bound inside Xaml. (Whether or not this confusion is good or bad for them depends on your world view!)

Comment: The author of the video himself answered? :)

Comment: @jari - Stuart's support is why MvvmCross is so awesome!